# The center of $M_n(R)$ is the set of scalar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Here is the question I want to solve:

Prove that the center of the ring $M_n(R)$ is the set of scalar matrices.

Here is a solution I found on the internet:

> [image]

I am not sure what exactly the main ideas of the solution, also I do not understand what is "Bis" in the solution, could someone clarify these for me or at least show me a cleaner solution than what is given?

Here is the link to the picture I included above: https://linearalgebras.com/solution-abstract-algebra-exercise-7-2-7.html

Comment: Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. [Here are many of the reasons why it's bad to do so](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: Even better, when the source is a legitimate online source, you should include a link to the page you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the word "is" and a mistake in $\LaTeX$ formatting.

$E_{pq}BE_{st} =E_{pq}E_{st}B $ if $B$ is assumed to be central.

$E_{pq}BE_{st}=E_{pt}b_{qs}$ by the properties of the matrices used.

So it reads

> Note that the $p,t$ entry of $E_{pq}BE_{st}=E_{pq}E_{st}B$ **is** $b_{qs}$

which is true since the product is $E_{pt}b_{qs}$